# Passing raw binary image to Azure Cognitive Services API

Tags: python, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I want to use [Analyze Images API](https://westcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/computer-vision-v3-2/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499f21b/console) from Azure with raw Python requests passing binary image data rather than URL. I use the io module to get binary data from the image

```py
with io.BytesIO() as output:
    tmp_imp.save(output, format="JPEG")
    contents = output.getvalue()

payload = {
    {'url': contents}
}
```

Then I pass it as 'url' to payload

```py
response = requests.post(analyze_url, headers=headers, params=params, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

The error I receive indicates there's a JSON format error, but I don't understand how to fix it

```json
{'error': {'code': 'InvalidArgument', 'innererror': {'code': 'BadArgument', 'message': 'JSON format error.'}, 'message': 'JSON format error.'}}
```

URLs work fine, but I want to use specifically binary image data without resorting to Azure Python packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the scenario, I have reproduced the issue.
[image]

To solve this, you can directly **pass the image data** and change the **content type** in your code snippet.

Below is the updated script:

```py
import  requests
import  io
def  analyze_image(image_data):
    analyze_url = "https://<endpoint>.cognitiveservices.azure.com/vision/v3.2/analyze"
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '<your-subscription-key>',
    
    params = {
    "visualFeatures": "Categories,Description,Color",
    }
    response = requests.post(analyze_url, headers=headers,params=params, data=image_data)
    return  response.json()
    
if  __name__ == '__main__':
    image_path = "OIP.jpg"
    with  open(image_path, "rb") as  image_file:
        image_data = image_file.read()
    result = analyze_image(image_data)
    print(result)
```

Updated Script successfully executed.

Output [image]

Comment: Thank you! Changing the content type definitely did the job!